# How to Fail a Test by reading the log line of Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework, ui-automation

I am new to robot framework and I have a custom library written in Python
I want to read the log line of perticular Test Keyword Step and check if it has a xxxx string in it and want to fail it if matches ,
I know we can use SHOULD NOT CONTAIN $container xxxx
with this if I try fail it should work but , Iam not getting how I can store the value of message to a $variable(container) to check it matches or not can anybody help on this?

in the below code ValidateProdIdle is a Custom library keyword and checks if a Item exists or not and prints accordingly like exists or Doesnt exists ,I want to read the string log , how?

Sample Code :

```
*** Test Cases ***
Launch APAMA Test Case
    Log     ${SWRoot}
    Setup Virtual Drive  ${SWRoot}  ${SWPlatform}  ${MachineSrNo}
    [Documentation]    Demo Test for Robot Framework
    Log    ${MESSAGE}
    Launch APAMA EmptyMainFrame
    ValidateProdIdle
    ValidateProdIdle    Log     SHOULD NOT CONTAIN    Doesnt  # does this way is correct?
```

Comment: Don't do that - checking the logs for a string; as you say this is a custom keyword, change it to either fail inside it based on the condition, or - to return value(s) that you read and act upon.

Comment: Yes , I added raise Exception, ElementNotfound error  in my Library itself so that RF  will fail and display the message I give in exception.

Comment: Would it not be easier to store the message as variable at test level scope and check whether that would contain the word you're looking for?